# mysql multiple joins on one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 table in a database , I need joins Four tables together but I can't Two more tables joins

```
$query = '
SELECT
   movie_title,genre_label,movie_year,director_name,movie_genre,movie_director,movie_actor
FROM
   general LEFT JOIN genre ON movie_genre = genre_id AND
   general LEFT JOIN movie_directors ON movie_director = director_id
WHERE
   general.movie_genre = genre.genre_id AND
   general.movie_director = movie_directors.director_id
ORDER BY
  movie_year';
```

my Browser show this Error:

```
Unknown column 'general' in 'on clause'
```

please Help Me , Thankes

Comment: Provide the Table definitions and some sample data and expected output.

Comment: This is completely wrong syntax.

Comment: Once you have specified the JOINS, you don't need to add the same condition in a WHERE clause. In your case you can completely get rid of the WHERE clause.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Please explain more, I am a newbie

Comment: Ok the query is wrong. Now to provide you the solution we would need the table structures with the column name. Also some sample data and what would be your desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to insert AND between joins and repeat the table you are querying.
Your query should be like this:

```
$query = '
SELECT
movie_title,genre_label,movie_year,director_name,movie_genre,movie_director,movie_actor
FROM
  general 
  LEFT JOIN genre ON movie_genre = genre_id 
  LEFT JOIN movie_directors ON movie_director = director_id
ORDER BY
  movie_year';
```

Answer (score 0):

it does not work?

```
SELECT movie_title,genre_label,movie_year,director_name,movie_genre,movie_director,movie_actor
FROM
   general 
   LEFT JOIN genre ON general.movie_genre = genre.genre_id
   LEFT JOIN movie_directors ON general.movie_director = movie_directors.director_id
ORDER BY
  movie_year';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
movie_title,genre_label,movie_year,
director_name,movie_genre,movie_director,movie_actor
FROM general 
LEFT JOIN genre ON general.movie_genre = genre.genre_id 
LEFT JOIN movie_directors ON general.movie_director = movie_directors.director_id
ORDER BY movie_year
```

Your JOIN/WHERE syntax is not correct. WHERE clause is not needed in your case. Additionally it is a good practice to specify the column names using table alias in your SELECT and ORDER BY statements.

**Note:** The above query statement is based on information provided in the question. The query can change if the OP adds table structure information int the question since it is not clear on what tables should the 2nd JOIN take place.